# Matlab - Undefined Error for Input Arguments of Type Double

Tags: matlab, double, undefined, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a function that does what `conv2(h1,h2,A)` & `conv2(...'shape')` does without using the built-in function. (speed is currently not an issue). as defined here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

These are my commands:

```
    imgC = imread('camerman.tif');
    imgC = double(imgC);

    sigma = 1;
    inp = (-1 .*2.5 .*sigma):1:(2.5 .* sigma);                                  
    gauss1d = (1/(sigma .* sqrt(2*pi))).*exp(-(inp.^2/(2.*sigma.*sigma)));      
    gaussprime = diff(gauss1d);       

    x = conv2fft(gaussprime,1,imgC , 'same');   
    y = conv2fft(1,gaussprime.',imgC , 'same'); 
    blur = conv2fft (gauss1d, gauss1d, imgC );
```

This is my error:

```
    Undefined function 'convfft' for input arguments of type 'double'.
    Error in conv2fft (line 81) `if size(convfft(a(1,:),r),1)==1`
```

If I run the same commands but use the `conv2` function:

```
    imgC = imread('camerman.tif');
    imgC = double(imgC);

    sigma = 1;
    inp = (-1 .*2.5 .*sigma):1:(2.5 .* sigma);                                  
    gauss1d = (1/(sigma .* sqrt(2*pi))).*exp(-(inp.^2/(2.*sigma.*sigma)));      
    gaussprime = diff(gauss1d);       

    x = conv2(gaussprime,1,imgC , 'same');   
    y = conv2(1,gaussprime.',imgC , 'same'); 
    blur = conv2(gauss1d, gauss1d, imgC );
```

It works fine?... I've been searching around and staring at this code for hours. I just can't see it. Anyone notice what is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Undefined function 'xxx' for input arguments of type 'double'` typically indicates that the function `xxx` is not on the path.

To confirm that this is indeed the issue, type `which convfft` at the command line, since `which` should indicate where Matlab knows the file is located.

If the file is not found, make sure that it exists on your computer, and add the file's parent folder to the Matlab path.

Comment: You certainly know your Matlab. I just did this and it returns `'convfft' not found.`...

Comment: I believe it already knows the path as its finds the function being called and converts the image to a grayscale and saves it first (which it achieves). It only errors at the convfft. I've since changed the convfft to conv2fft (function name typo) and now the error is `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in cannyWorkingOn>conv2fft (line 295)
                y3(:,ii)=conv2fft(y2(:,ii),c);`

Comment: @Reanimation: Matlab knows `conv2fft`, but not `convfft`. Use your file system to search for the file. If it isn't found, it should be available on the File Exchange.

Comment: @jonas- seems you are good at explaining things clearly, could you explain the segment of code:

    `sigma = 1;`
    `inp = (-1 .*2.5 .*sigma):1:(2.5 .* sigma);` 
    `gauss1d = (1/(sigma .* sqrt(2*pi))).*exp(-(inp.^2/(2.*sigma.*sigma)));` 
    `gaussprime = diff(gauss1d);` 

I understand sigma is the total sum of all values in the kernel/grid. But what part of this code determines the size? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Reanimation: The above calculates a Gaussian-shaped kernel, as well as the first numerical derivative (`gaussprime`). `sigma` gives the width of the Gaussian, which also determines the kernel size, which, in turn, is defined as 2.5 `sigma` in both directions. The kernel is normalized to 1 regardless of `sigma` - change `sigma` to 2 and see what happens. As a side note, please ask new questions as new question instead of in a comment, since there, the question will not be useful for any subsequent user.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks so much. Good explanation.
Oh of course. Sorry. I just didn't want you to not see the question. I will do that in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: so to change the kernel to a 9x9, i would simple change the value 2.5?

Comment: @Reanimation: Depends on what you want. The value 2.5 has been chosen so that the Gaussian is nearly zero. If you shrink this window, the filter will not be near zero at the edges, and thus become more similar to an average filter. If you shrink `sigma`, the kernel window shrinks as well, but your Gaussian will be much narrower.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24528/discussion-between-reanimation-and-jonas)