# Matlab Will Not Add Path

Tags: matlab, function, path, path-finding

I am trying to call a function from the command window, but I constantly am obstacle by the message

```
Undefined function 'gDiscrPdfRnd' for
input arguments of type 'double'.
```

So, I searched this messaged in google. According to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874828/matlab-undefined-error-for-input-arguments-of-type-double), a possible cause for this is that matlab can not find the file. I found this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html#btpdojn-1) which tells of how to add the path. So, I typed in the command

```
addpath('C:\Users\Eli\Documents\MATLAB\final project\help')
```

and then I typed in

```
which gDiscrPdfRnd
```

which gave me the error 'gDiscrPdfRnd' not found. How can I fix this?

EDIT: The output of cd('C:\Users\Eli\Documents\MATLAB\final project\help');dir is

```
.                       IdealGasSimulation.zip  randpdf                 
..                      gDiscrPdfRnd funct      randpdf.zip             
IdealGasSimulation      gDiscrPdfRnd funct.zip
```

Comment: You sure, 'gDiscrPdfRnd.m'  is in 'C:\Users\Eli\Documents\MATLAB\final project\help'?

Comment: what is the output of `cd('C:\Users\Eli\Documents\MATLAB\final project\help');dir`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I am certain.

Comment: @Daniel I just edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no file `gDiscrPdfRnd.m` in the folder, put it into the `help` directory or add the folder where the `gDiscrPdfRnd.m` is placed.

Comment: Okay, I was able to get this to work. However, know I am getting the same error message with built-in matlab functions. For instance, when I used datasample, I got the message Undefined function 'datasample' for input arguments of type 'double'. I then typed in "which datasample", and it said "datasample' not found." Why is this happening? Would it have anything to do with matlab's new update?

Comment: datasample is part of the statistics toolbox. Is it installed and licensed?

Comment: ...I don't have it. Is the only alternative to pay for the toolbox, in order to use it?